# Decision fusion of multiple features from small data set

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

This is not a much specific question, I just want to gather idea from colleagues in this forum.

My question is;

I estimated human height, size and cloth color from video data collected from one camera, let's call these features and I  have similar set of people as another data set but collected from another camera. So I want to identify the people in the second dataset if they match the features in the first dataset (something like re-identification) but, I am confused on how to fuse the features together and how to match or rank them(which is like classification).

Please I need suggestions and advise.

Comment: Can you state more specifically the data you have and the type of prediction you'd like to make? Can you share what approaches did you think of/ try? Specifically, do you have the same features (e.g. height, size, cloth color, etc.) on the second data set as well?

Comment: @etov, thanks for your respose, I have 100 subjects in the first dataset. height, weight, cloth color are resultant euclidean measure after object extraction. I have these same features and subjects in the second dataset. In literature have read (http://www.eurecom.fr/fr/publication/3442/download/mm-publi-3442_1.pdf), they used weighted parameter for fusing the features and they used thesame thing for the second dataset,, so they did some matching which I dont understand leading to a confusion matrix (but they never used any classifier).

Comment: The paper you refer to seems to reference another paper,http://www.eurecom.fr/fr/publication/3247/download/mm-publi-3247_1.pdf, which describes the general classification method. It seem to be based on Naive-Bayes classification approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Canonical Correlation Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation). Excerpts from the Wiki page:

A typical use for canonical correlation in the experimental context is to take two sets of variables and see what is common amongst the two sets.

Visualization of the results of canonical correlation is usually through bar plots of the coefficients of the two sets of variables for the pairs of canonical variates showing significant correlation. Some authors suggest that they are best visualized by plotting them as heliographs, a circular format with ray like bars, with each half representing the two sets of variables e.g. ["Canonical correlation analysis: Use of composite heliographs for representing multiple patterns"](http://ti.arc.nasa.gov/m/profile/adegani/Composite_Heliographs.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I agree it sounds like a classification problem. You will need to setup two classes though, something like human / non-human.

Then, you have to check if the features you chose are the good ones for your particular problem. You could plot your features for each individual in your database; which means, 2D plot x = feature1, y = feature2, do it for your whole database from feature 1 to n. It will allow you to know whether a feature is relevant or not in the task to classify a human being from its environment.

Now, it look like you're trying to do binary classification : human / not human. [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) is good for such a task, but if you're not familiar with it or with [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) in general you could start with an easier algorithm, such as [kNN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm).

Don't forget to normalize your data between let's say [0 1], I think the reason is quite obvious ! Once you have chosen your classification algorithm, you will have to quantify how good your algorithm is doing its task. For this, you could try [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) (leave-one-out ...etc.), then [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).

Have fun !